# How to cast Django form to dict where keys are field id in template and values are initial values?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a huge django form and I need to create dict where keys are field id in template and values are initial values?
Something like this:

```
{'field1_id_in_template': value1, ...}
```

Does somebody know how do that?

I can add prefix 'id_' for each field name in form.fields dictionary but I can have a problem if somebody change id for widget.attrs

Comment: Are you looking for something like this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values ?

Comment: No, keys in initial are not ids in template

Comment: Answers go in answers, not the question itself, see [answer]. I've added it as a community-wiki, feel free to repost it under your own name and ping me to remove the CW one.

Answer (score 1):

This is method of CBV:

```
def post_ajax(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = ChooseForm(request.POST, log=log)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save()
        inst_form = InstanceForm(instance=instance, account=request.user)
        fields = {}
        for name in inst_form.fields:
            if name in inst_form.initial:
                fields[inst_form.auto_id % name] = inst_form.initial[name]
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps({'status': 'OK','fields':fields},
            mimetype='appplication/json'
        )
    assert False
```

And this a reason why I do that:
With this response I can write something like this on client. Now I don't need to manualy initialize all fields on the page

```
function mergeFields(data) { 
    for(var id in data) { 
        $("#"+id).val(data[id]).change(); 
    } 
}
```

Originally added to the question body itself [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17677297/2).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the auto_id set to True then you can get the id with form_object_instance.field_name.auto_id. With that in mind you can create your dict by iterating over the form object.

I am just wondering why you would need to do such a processing as the form object is usually used to encapsulate such behaviors...

Comment: I added some notes in questions which explains why I do that

Answer (score 0):

you can try **getattr**.

For example, you have a known key list as

```
['field1_id_in_template', 'field2_id_in_template', ...]
```

Then:

```
my_values = dict()
for key in key_list:
    value = getattr(your_form, key)
    # now do something with it
    my_values[key] = deal_with(value)
```

Comment: how about: for key in dir(your_form): if key.find('_id_') then do something, else continue.