# django: form to json

Tags: json, django, forms, serialization, django-forms

I am trying to serialize my form into the json format. My view:

```
form = CSVUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
data_to_json={}
data_to_json = simplejson.dumps(form.__dict__)
return HttpResponse(data_to_json, mimetype='application/json')
```

I have the error `<class 'django.forms.util.ErrorList'> is not JSON serializable`. What to do to handle django forms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to look at the package called [django-remote-forms](https://github.com/WiserTogether/django-remote-forms):

> A package that allows you to serialize django forms, including fields
>   and widgets into Python dictionary for easy conversion into JSON and
>   expose over API

Also see:

- [How to cast Django form to dict where keys are field id in template and values are initial values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677297/how-to-cast-django-form-to-dict-where-keys-are-field-id-in-template-and-values-a)

Comment: Anything newer? This package is abandoned.

Comment: Also looking for a modern solution

Answer (score 9):

Just in case anyone is new to Django, you can also do something like this:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

form = YourForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    data = form.cleaned_data
    return JsonResponse(data) 
else:
    data = form.errors.as_json()
    return JsonResponse(data, status=400)
```

- JsonResponse: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects
- Form.cleaned_data: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data
- Form.errors.as_json(): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors.as_json